# How to Split Data and concat based on List Values in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to Split Data and Map Values based on the list.

```
df

Id      String
1       JHA PQR 20 STO KJAN
2       LKS JHA PLA; NIYM
3       LMA\KHA 20 HYS,KNSN
4       JHA, PQR STO 20 KJAM
5       JHA PQR|STO/KJAOP

List_to_map = [JHA, LMA, STO, PQR, LKS]

df_output

Id      String                 Values
1       JHA PQR 20 STO KJAN    JHA+PQR+STO
2       LKS JHA PLA; NIYM      LKS+JHA
3       LMA\KHA 20 HYS,KNSN    LMA
4       JHA, PQR STO 20 KJAM   JHA+PQR+STO
5       JHA PQR|STO/KJAOP      JHA+PQR+STO
```

I need to map the Column String Values to list, if list exist those values it needs to concat those values and create a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on non-word character with regex `\W`, then get the common elements with `List_to_map` by [`np.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html).  Finally, join the matching strings with `+` using [`.str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), as follows:

```
import numpy as np
List_to_map = ['JHA', 'LMA', 'STO', 'PQR', 'LKS']

df['Values'] = df['String'].str.split(r'\W').apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, List_to_map)).str.join('+')
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   Id             String       Values
0   1   JHA PQR STO KJAN  JHA+PQR+STO
1   2  LKS JHA PLA; NIYM      JHA+LKS
2   3   LMA\KHA HYS,KNSN          LMA
3   4  JHA, PQR STO KJAM  JHA+PQR+STO
4   5  JHA PQR|STO/KJAOP  JHA+PQR+STO
```

Alternatively, **if you want to maintain the sequence of original string**, you can also use:

```
df['Values'] = df['String'].str.split(r'\W').apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y in List_to_map]).str.join('+')
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   Id             String       Values
0   1   JHA PQR STO KJAN  JHA+PQR+STO
1   2  LKS JHA PLA; NIYM      LKS+JHA
2   3   LMA\KHA HYS,KNSN          LMA
3   4  JHA, PQR STO KJAM  JHA+PQR+STO
4   5  JHA PQR|STO/KJAOP  JHA+PQR+STO
```

Note that using the numpy function `np.intersect1d()` is faster than using Python list comprehension.  However, the matching list will be based on the `List_to_map` string sequence.  If string concat sequence is not important, I would recommend using `np.intersect1d()` for faster execution time.

Comment: I have edited the question with some numeric values, please check it once. its is giving error for float object as it is not iterable. TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @denzfranc You can try convert the column to string first eg. `df['Values'] = df['String'].astype(str).str.split(r'\W').apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, List_to_map)).str.join('+')`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with word boundaries for each value of lsit and then join together by [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in List_to_map)
df['Values'] = df['String'].astype(str).str.findall(pat).str.join('+')
print (df)
   Id             String       Values
0   1   JHA PQR STO KJAN  JHA+PQR+STO
1   2  LKS JHA PLA; NIYM      LKS+JHA
2   3   LMA\KHA HYS,KNSN          LMA
3   4  JHA, PQR STO KJAM  JHA+PQR+STO
4   5  JHA PQR|STO/KJAOP  JHA+PQR+STO
```

Comment: I have edited the question with some numeric values, please check it once. its is giving error for float object as it is not iterable. TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @denzfranc - Maybe need `df['Values'] = df['String'].astype(str).str.findall(pat).str.join('+')`